# ROS Answers SE migration: Collider usage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm capturing point cloud data from a kinect, from which I'd like to build a collision map in order to do planning. It seems the collider package is the appropriate thing to use, but without any documentation, I can't figure out how to get it to work. Has anyone used collider, and give an example of how to use it? I've created a launch file similar to the one here:

http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/collision_octomap.html

As well as a YAML file for specifying the point cloud source. However, when I try to run it, I get the following errors:

```
[ WARN] [1338577423.133577415]: No multi dof joints specified, including root to world conversion
[ WARN] [1338577423.134981502]: No groups for planning specified in /robot_description_planning/groups
[ WARN] [1338577423.135062448]: Can't do anything without a root transform
[ WARN] [1338577423.139176031]: No default collision operations specified
```

And the collision_map_out and point_cloud_out topics are not being published. How do I get this to work? It seems like it should be very simple.

EDIT:
Thanks Armin, that works perfectly!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35485/collider-usage/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2012-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For that use case you can have a look at [octomap_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_server), it should be easier to configure. It will integrate sensor data over time and also publish a collision map.

Collider is pretty geared towards the PR2's stereo sensor and arm_navigation.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2